# Joining two tables with a LIKE statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join my tables with a LIKE STATEMENT and my current query is this :

```
SELECT
    COUNT(comment_id) AS nb,
    produit.nom
FROM
    comments
INNER JOIN produit ON comments.comment_location like (select '%'+produit.id+'%')
GROUP BY
    comment_location
```

and the SQL FOR THE TABLES is this :

table comments:

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
 `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `comment_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `comment_content` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `comment_location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `comments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

table produit :

```
CREATE TABLE `produit` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `nom` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `description` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `categorie` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `image` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `prix` float NOT NULL,
 `quantite` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `prix_initiale` float NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `FK_CATEGORIE` (`categorie`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_CATEGORIE` FOREIGN KEY (`categorie`) REFERENCES `categorie` (`nom`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

my query does execute but doesn't return the table i was looking for 
but if i try replacing produit.id in  (select '%'+produit.id+'%') with a constant the table shows the corresponding rows .

What am i doing wrong

Comment: Try `LIKE CONCAT('%', produit.id, '%')`. Now the real question is _why would the `comment.comment_location` value **contain** the`produit.id`?_

Comment: This fixed it thanks !!

Comment: The relationship between your tables seems very odd. I really hope `comment_location` doesn't contain a list of `produit.id` values

Comment: it's just for a school project we only have a single.php file for all the products in the website and the content changes according to the GET variable ... but it works fine

Comment: @Phil... maybe if we're looking for produit.id 111, we also want to find matches for comments that include produit.id values of 1114, 5111, 21117, et al.  hmmm. that wouldn't normally be desired behavior, but apparently this is a requirement that has to be satisfied for a school project.

Comment: @New_ToQT I suggest you read this and get extra credit ~ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Comment: Also, your `GROUP BY` should contain the non-aggregate columns in your `SELECT` clause, ie `produit.nom` **not** `comment_location`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify query as below. You dont need SELECT again in the LIKE clause.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(comment_id) AS nb,
    produit.nom
FROM
    comments
INNER JOIN produit ON comments.comment_location like CONCAT('%',produit.id,'%')
GROUP BY
    comment_location
```

Comment: Pretty sure MySQL doesn't have a string concatenation operator

Comment: @Phil Sorry. I am from MSSQL background. I should have checked for the syntax. updated the answer

Comment: yea this doesn't execute but thank's anyways Phil fixed my issue

Comment: @New_ToQT, please add your answer, so that it will help others in future

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(comment_id) AS nb, produit.nom AS nom FROM comments INNER JOIN produit ON comments.comment_location LIKE CONCAT('%', produit.id, '%')

GROUP BY comment_location

by @Phil